# Planar Geometry question

Tags: geometry

Suppose I have three points $p$, $f_1$, and $f_2$. I want to place a third point $f_3$ such that if you extend the line segments $pf_1$ and $pf_2$ into full lines, $f_3$ is going to be on the opposite side of $pf_1$ as $f_2$ is, and $f_3$ will also be on the opposite side of $pf_2$ from where $f_1$ is. What I want to show is that the point $p$ will be in the triangle formed by $f_1$, $f_2$, and $f_3$. I'm about 98% sure this is a correct statement, I'm just not sure how to go about proving its true beyond "drawing pretty pictures".

EDIT Clarification: If you take the line through $p$ and $f_1$, then you have partitioned the plane into two parts. The assumption is that $f_3$ must be in the partition that $f_2$ is not in.

Comment: I'd have thought pictures are fine, as long as you can prove they're general.

Comment: I just can't understand what "to be on the opposite side of $\,pf_1\,$ as $\,f_2\,$ is..." can possibly mean.

Comment: @DonAntonio $pf_1$ is a line so it divides the plane into two half planes. $f_2$ is in one of those, $f_3$ is in the other.

Comment: Oh, now **that's** clear, @user69810 . thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an idea:

By rotating, translating, reflecting, and rescaling, we can assume that $p$ is the origin, $f_1=(1,0)$, and $f_2=(x_0,y_0)$ with $y_0>0$.

**Case $1$:** $x_0=0$.  Then $f_3=(x_1,y_1)$ is any point in the third quadrant.  The line from $f_3$ to $f_2$ has positive $y$-intercept, and the line from $f_3$ to $f_1$ has negative $y$-intercept, so that $p$ is inside the triangle formed by $f_1$, $f_2$, and $f_3$.

**Case $2$:** $x_0>0$.  Then $f_3=(x_1,y_1)$ is any point satisfying

$$\frac{y_0}{x_0}x_1<y_1<0$$

These are exactly the inequalities you need to show that the line from $f_3$ to $f_2$ has positive $y$-intercept, and the line from $f_3$ to $f_1$ has negative $y$-intercept, so that $p$ is inside the triangle formed by $f_1$, $f_2$, and $f_3$.

**Case $3$:** $x_0<0$.  Proceed as in Case $2$ using the inequalities:

$$y_1<0,\qquad y_1<\frac{y_0}{x_0}x_1$$

Comment: Thank you. This got me where I needed to go, although Case 3 isn't as straightforward as Case 2, since $x_1$ can be positive, negative, or zero, which means that there are actually three different subcases here. They all work out without too much trouble though.